# CSS Sticky header goes away after scrolling the div height

Tags: css, scroll, sticky

Edit: The issue has been fixed. Unfortunately it wasn't anything in the code I posted here so posting an answer wouldn't do much good. It was a framework issue.

Just as the title suggests, I have a div (with a table) with a sticky `<thead>` by using `position: sticky;` in my CSS. But after scrolling the div height the header just scrolls up with the content.

The html code is something like this

```
<div class="tablewrapper">
    <table>
        <thead>content with tr and th's</thead>
        <tbody>more content with tr and td's</tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My CSS code is like this:

```
.tablewrapper {
    overflow: auto;
}

.tablewrapper table {
    /* This is empty */
}

.tablewrapper thead {
    display: block;
    position: sticky;
    overflow: visible
}

.tablewrapper tbody {
    overflow: visible;
    display: block;
}
```

The scrollbar comes from the `.tablewrapper`.

How can I make the `thead` stay sticky?

Also, to clarify, The Code is much more advanced then here, so unfortunately I am forced to have the scrollbar on the `tablewrapper`.

A pure CSS fix would be preferable

Comment: Which browser are you testing it with? It seems like only Firefox have support for sticky table elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility

Comment: in Chrome. according to w3schools Chrome does support the position sticky attribute. And it does work for the first 500px that i scroll.

Comment: I guess you need to use `position: fixed` since Chrome doesnt support the position sticky with tables...

Answer (score 0):

Add `Top: 0;` the thead tag will stick when it will reach the top

```
.tablewrapper thead {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  Top:0;
  overflow: visible
}
```